# Work around type-erasure when doing pattern-match of a list / sequence in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I'm having a situation like this:

I have a sequence that I need to match. Actually, in the "case" I only need to match against a sequence whose elements are of tuple `(String, Seq[String])` but I couldn't find a way to do that, so I resorted to the technique I read on web: decapitate the seq, match against the first element, and re-attach inside the block to get the original seq.

The problem with that approach is: type erasure.

The resulting seq from the expression "head +: rest" is a `Seq[Any]` instead of `Seq[(String, Seq[String])]`

That's why the `tuple_.1` gives compile error (line 153 in the attached image).

How to work around this situation?

[image]

Comment: Type erasure isn't your problem. Your problem is that the `Nil` case results in a `String` but your second case results in a `Unit` (the return type of `println`). Therefore, `hhh` is the least upper bound of these two types, which is `Any`, and does not have a `.map` method. There are a lot of basic errors in your Scala, and it's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish. You will probably have to ask a question that incorporates your expected result.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I just found about it (apart some other coding error). Thanks for pointing out. I'll update my question note, putting screenshot of updated (working) code. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't include code in screenshots—it's hard to read, makes search less useful, and hurts accessibility.

Comment: Ok, I'll post the working code now. Btw... the question is a simplified version of a code I'm working on.... In my code I'm still getting a situation where the "tuple" is not recongnized as tuple by compiler, but as Any. Still looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad, there are a couple of coding errors in the above screenshot; from the case block of sequence matching I should have added another line to the end: complexSeqReconstructed.

Apart from that, there's a little detail: from the "case Nil", I also have to return an empty Seq of type Seq[(String, Seq[String])] ... that matches the return from the other case. That way Scala will correctly perform type inference. Otherwise the line hhh.map wouldn't compile (it will say, Object hhh doesn't have map method).

So here's the updated (working) code:

[image]

```
val theComplexSeq: Seq[(String, Seq[String])] = Seq(
  ("the_key_a", Seq("value_a_1", "value_a_2"))
)

val hhh = theComplexSeq match {
  case Nil => {
    Seq[(String, Seq[String])]()
  }
  case (head: (String, Seq[String])) +: rest => {
    println(head)
    println(rest) 

    val complexSeqReconstructed = head +: rest
    println(complexSeqReconstructed)

    complexSeqReconstructed
  }
}

hhh.map {tuple =>
  println(tuple._1 + "->" + tuple._2)
  tuple
}
```

Comment: I've pulled your Edit out of the question and put it in your answer. Answers should not be provided in the original question.